# view not updating after variable change

Tags: angular, typescript, templates, view

I have an event that triggers a function in the component:

**componentA.ts**

```
    html = 'hey';

      this.onElementSelected(r => this.change());

      public change() {

      console.log(this.html);
      if (this.html === 'hey') {

        this.html = 'oh, hello!';
        console.log(this.html);
      } else {
        this.html = 'hey';
      }
  }
```

**componentA.html**

This is the code of the associated template:

```
<div *ngIf="html">{{html}}</div>
```

I can see the html variable change with console.log(), but it doesn't change in the template.
How to update the template? Please do not suggest to use a button in the template as so:

```
  <button (click)="change()">Change</button>
```

I already tested this and it works, but I need the event of change to be triggered by the component itself.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is `this.onElementSelected`?

Comment: This may be due to changes that aren't in your example code. Could you try reproducing the issue here? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bepvmn

Comment: @ExplosionPills it is an event triggered by the click on a tool that I have in the page..

Comment: @ExplosionPills sorry my mistake. With onInint works as you show. The problem is when the function change() is called by this tool that I have on the page. It is difficult to reproduce the situation...the tool is displayed by the component itself and triggers events. One of these events fires the function change()..so the variable changes, but I think the view was already uploaded at onInint..so it doesn't detect the change..

Comment: If updating from a service, use ApplicationRef instead to run change detection for the whole application.

Answer (score 2):

Did you use ChangedetectionStrategy.OnPush? This option decouples Angular from auto updating your view. Hence you have to tell when Angular should update the view.

If so tell your component's view to update:

1. inject the ChangeDetectorRef via your constructor:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

...

constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

2. tell Angular to rerender the component by calling in your change()-function
   after the 'this.html'-assignment:

```
if (this.html === 'hey') {
        this.html = 'oh, hello!';
        this.cd.detectChanges();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

try injecting **ngZone** in your component and execute your change in its run function like so

```
import {NgZone} from '@angular/core';  

class YourClass {

        constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {
                this.htmlSource = new BehaviorSubject('hey');
               this.html$ = this.htmlSource.asObservable();
          }

     this.onElementSelected(r => this.change());

    public change() {
         console.log(this.htmlSource.value);
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
     if (this.htmlSource.value === 'hey') {
          this.htmlSource.next('oh, hello!');
         console.log(this.htmlSource.value);
     } else {
        this.htmlSource.next('hey');
     }

     });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an Observable with BehaviorSubject like this:

```
public html$: Observable<string>;
private htmlSource: BehaviorSubject<string>();
constructor() {
   this.htmlSource = new BehaviorSubject('hey');
   this.html$ = this.htmlSource.asObservable();
}
  this.onElementSelected(r => this.change());

  public change() {

  console.log(this.htmlSource.value);
  if (this.htmlSource.value === 'hey') {

    this.htmlSource.next('oh, hello!');
    console.log(this.htmlSource.value);
  } else {
    this.htmlSource.next('hey');
   }
}
```

Then in the component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="html$ | async as html">{{html}}</div>
```

Comment: Same. I see the variable change with console.log(), but there is no change in the view.

Comment: That's rare... can you upload all the component code and the module where he is declared? Also if you can upload the component code to https://stackblitz.com/ that would be very useful so I can try to reproduce the error and fix it.